# Informix trigger to change inserted values

Tags: informix, eventtrigger

I would like to change a couple of column values before they get inserted.
I am using Informix as database.

I have a table consisting of  3 columns: Name (NVARCHAR), Type (INT), Plan (NVARCHAR).

Every time a new record is inserted, I would like to check the Name value before inserting it. If the Name starts with an F, I would like to set the Type value to 1 and the Plan Name to "Test"

In short, what I want the trigger to do is:

1. For every new insertion, first check if Name value starts with F.
2. If yes, set the Type and Plan to 1 and "Test" then insert.
3. If no, insert the values as-is.

I have looked up the CREATE TRIGGER statement with BEFORE and AFTER. However, I would like to have a clearer example. My case would probably involve BEFORE though.

Answer (score 5):

The answer of @user3243781 get close, but did not work because it returns the error:

> -747    Table or column matches object referenced in triggering statement.
>
> This error is returned when a triggered SQL statement acts on the
>   triggering table, or when both statements are updates, and the column
>   that is updated in the triggered action is the same as the column that
>   the triggering statement updates.

So the alternative is handle with the NEW variable directly.
For that you need to use a procedure with the ***triggers reference*** resource, which means the procedure will able to act like the trigger by self.

Below is my example which I run with dbaccess over a Informix v11.70.
This resource is available only for versions +11 of the engine, as far I remember.

```
create table teste ( Name NVARCHAR(100), Type INT , Plan NVARCHAR(100) );
Table created.

create procedure check_name_values()
  referencing new as n for teste ;;

  define check_type integer ;;
  define check_plan NVARCHAR ;;

  if upper(n.name) like 'F%' then
    let n.type = 1;;
    let n.plan = "Test";;

  end if
end procedure ;
Routine created.

;

create trigger trg_tablename_ins
    insert on teste
    referencing new as new
    for each row
    (
            execute procedure check_name_values() with trigger references

    );
Trigger created.

insert into teste values ('cesar',99,'myplan');
1 row(s) inserted.
insert into teste (name) values ('fernando');
1 row(s) inserted.
insert into teste values ('Fernando',100,'your plan');
1 row(s) inserted.



select * from teste ;
name  cesar
type  99
plan  myplan

name  fernando
type  1
plan  Test

name  Fernando
type  1
plan  Test

3 row(s) retrieved.



drop table if exists teste;
Table dropped.


drop procedure if exists check_name_values;
Routine dropped.
```

Comment: I have tried to create a stored proc in this manner but I receive a syntax error when trying to add the IF statement. I get the same issue when I tried to add the IF statement directly to the trigger. On version 11.70.FC8

Comment: Beware — the double semicolons are probably a syntax error; you should only use a single semicolon to separate (non-empty) statements, and not in all contexts.  (Semicolons in SPL are a fraught topic.)

Answer (score 0):

```
create trigger trg_tablename_ins
    insert on tablename
    referencing new as new
    for each row
    (
            execute procedure check_name_values
            (
                    new.name,
                    new.type, 
                    new.plan
            )

    );



create procedure check_name_values 
(
   name NVARCHAR,
   new_type integer,
   new_plan NVARCHAR,
)
define check_type integer ;
define check_plan NVARCHAR ;

  let check_type = 1;
  let check_plan = "Test";

   if name = 'F%'
   then
       insert into tablename (name,type,plan) values (name,check_type,check_plan);
   else
       insert into tablename (name,type,plan) values (name,new_type,new_plan);
   end if ;

end procedure ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version an adaptation of an old example I found in the informix usenet group.

It is possible to update columns in a trigger statement but not very straight forward. You have to use stored procedures an the `into` statement with the `execute procedure` command.

It worked here for IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC11WE.

```
drop table if exists my_table;
drop sequence if exists my_table_seq;

create table my_table (   
   id                 INTEGER 
                      NOT NULL, 
   col_a              char(32) 
                      NOT NULL, 
   col_b              char(20)  
                      NOT NULL,
   hinweis            char(64),
   uslu               char(12)
                      DEFAULT USER
                      NOT NULL,
   dtlu               DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND
                      DEFAULT CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND
                      NOT NULL
)
;

create sequence my_table_seq 
increment 1
start 1;


drop procedure if exists get_user_datetime();
create function get_user_datetime() returning char(12),datetime year to second;

   return user, current year to second;
end function 
;

drop trigger if exists ti_my_table;
create trigger ti_my_table insert on my_table referencing new as n for each row (
  execute function get_user_datetime() into uslu, dtlu
)
;
drop trigger if exists tu_my_table;
create trigger tu_my_table update on my_table referencing new as n for each row (
  execute function get_user_datetime() into uslu, dtlu
)
;




insert into my_table  values (my_table_seq.nextval, "a", "b", null, "witz", mdy(1,1,1900)) ;

SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE 1=1
;
```

Comment: It's also possible to create two functions an set the values in the trigger like this: create trigger ti_my_table insert on my_table referencing new as n for each row (
  execute function get_user() into uslu, execute function get_datetime() into dtlu
)