# How to resolve error code -747 in Informix?

Tags: sql, informix

I have a table that among other columns, has 4 columns used to store:

- when a row was inserted (`created_tm`)
- who has inserted the row (`created_by`)
- when a row was updated (`last_updated`)
- who had updated the row (`updated_by`)

I have created a trigger to populate `last_updated` and `updated_by` whenever an update statement occurs:

```
create trigger my_table_audit update on my_table referencing old as pre new as post    
for each row
(
    update my_table set last_updated = CURRENT year to second, 
    updated_by = USER where (id = pre.id)   
);
```

However when I update an ordinary column of a particular row, the update fails with:

```
[Code: -747, SQL State: IX000]  Table or column matches object
referenced in triggering statement.
```

Is there a way to work around this problem without having to explicitly name all the individual columns of the table for which the trigger should happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Informix, triggers that manipulate the table where they are defined are subject to several restrictions. The list is extensive, so I only link the online documentation (version 12.10):

- [CREATE TRIGGER statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0584.htm)
- [Re-entrancy of Triggers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0627.htm)

In your case, a possible solution is to make use of a trigger procedure to manipulate the values of the inserts/updates, as is explained by [ceinmart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469192/ceinmart) in his answer to [Informix trigger to change inserted values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380640/informix-trigger-to-change-inserted-values).

So using trigger procedures, it would be something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE self_audit
(
    id               SERIAL PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT pk_self_audit
    , col1           CHAR(3)
    , created_tm     DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION
    , created_by     CHAR(10)
    , last_updated   DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION
    , updated_by     CHAR(10)
);

CREATE PROCEDURE spti_self_audit ()
REFERENCING NEW AS new_insert FOR self_audit;

    LET new_insert.created_tm = CURRENT;
    LET new_insert.created_by = USER;
    LET new_insert.last_updated = CURRENT;
    LET new_insert.updated_by = USER;

END PROCEDURE;

CREATE TRIGGER ti_self_audit INSERT ON self_audit
REFERENCING NEW AS new_insert
FOR EACH ROW
(
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE spti_self_audit() WITH TRIGGER REFERENCES
);

CREATE PROCEDURE sptu_self_audit ()
REFERENCING NEW AS post OLD AS pre FOR self_audit;

    LET post.last_updated = CURRENT;
    LET post.updated_by = USER;

END PROCEDURE;

CREATE TRIGGER tu_self_audit UPDATE ON self_audit
REFERENCING NEW AS post OLD AS pre
FOR EACH ROW
(
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE sptu_self_audit() WITH TRIGGER REFERENCES
);
```

My understanding of this type of trigger routines is that we are directly manipulating the values that will be inserted/updated instead of doing more updates/inserts via the trigger action.

- [CREATE PROCEDURE statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0456.htm)
- [The REFERENCING and FOR Clauses](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0461.htm)

In this case, my update trigger only manipulates the values of the columns `last_updated` and `updated_by`, so a user can change the values of the columns `created_tm` and `created_by`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and the solution Luis. I used a slightly different solution (proposed by our DBAs), defining a function returning `CURRENT, USER` and executing it like `execute function populate_audit_fields() into my_table_audit`. Any pros/cons in comparison with the stored proc you can think of?

Comment: @Behrang I don't know if internally they are treated the same way by Informix, but the results seem to be the same. So use what works for you, unless you want to do some benchmarking.